# Bottle + Apache + WSGI + Sessions

Tags: python, session, wsgi, bottle

I'm trying to use sessions on a small CMS that I'm working on.

I'm testing, and I able to run sessions nicely using bottle as server. Code below:

```
# test.session.py

import bottle

from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}

app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)

@bottle.route('/set_session')
def session_test():
    varsession = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    varsession['value1'] = 'This is the value'
    return varsession['value1']

@bottle.route('/get_session')
def sessao():
    varsession = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    return varsession['value1']

bottle.run(app=app)
```

But I'm using Apache + modwsgi to run this CMS. And I'm bit confused where should I place imports etc... Should I put into the “adapter.wsgi” or should I place into the “.py” file?

# WSGI.file

```
import sys, os, bottle

sys.path = ['/filmes/appone'] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import appone # This loads your application

application = bottle.default_app()
```

---

```
# .py file


import bottle

from bottle import route, request, debug
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
'session.type': 'file',
'session.cookie_expires': 300,
'session.data_dir': './data',
'session.auto': True
}

app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)

@route('/')
def funcone():
    return "Home Page"

@route('/session_test')
def session_test():
    varsession = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    varsession['value1'] = 'This is the value'
    return varsession['value1']
```

I got a 500 error. And that's all I got.

By the way, where should I set debug True on Apache + WSGI?

I'm kind of new on Bottle/Python....

Comment: 500 Error -- what do you see in your error_log?  There will be a stack trace there which will help track down the problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will modify your # WSGI.file

```
import os

os.chdir('/filmes/') # the directory where your py files are, use the full linux system path
from appone import app # I assume appone.py is your main application

application = app
```

You are referencing the default_app(), which was replaced by app when you implement session in your code.